# Can I boot using the contents of a Windows Server Backup VHD?

Tags: boot, backup, windows-server-2012-r2

Yesterday morning I tried to attach my server machine to a domain running on one of my other server machines, something went wrong and I couldn't reach the machine after it rebooted.

I removed it from the domain to no effect, so I had to wipe & reinstall it. The backup catalog that Windows Server Backup made is apparently corrupted and I'm unable to restore it. I can however access the disk images (VHDs) of the drives that were backed-up, which includes everything on drive C:.

I've started copying the contents of the image to an empty NTFS partition on the server, with the intention of booting from it.

I [realise that I can't boot from it off-the-bat](https://superuser.com/questions/929154/windows-backup-vhd-file-format#comment1258377_929154), but if I run a boot sector repair in Windows RE (which my server provider provides via VNC) could I successfully boot from it (*lesson learnt, always have more than one backup*)?

Comment: Was it a virtual or physical machine? If it was a virtual, was it running off a physical disk or a virtual disk. If it was running off a virtual disk, what format was it?

Comment: @Dr.Ping It was physical, with a standard run-of-the-mill C:\ NTFS partition with a backup partition.

Comment: Great. That makes it easier. Does the vhd contain just one partition or two?

Comment: @Dr.Ping Just the one C:\ partition. I also have a backup image of a RAM disk but the RAM disk software also has its own image that it restores on boot. My priority is to get the one C:\ partition up and running as that contains most of the data.

Comment: Hello? Did it work?

Comment: @Dr.Ping I did not try, however your method would not work anyhow as I am unable to boot from the Windows installation disk (as I mentioned in the question).

Comment: I don't think you read my answer. Read it, and you'll see why I think that

Comment: @Dr.Ping `boot up with a Windows installation disk`, I cannot do that.

Comment: Also `take an empty disk and hook it into a functional computer`: the disk is inside a server which is located within a remote datacentre that I do not have access to, as stated within the question.

Comment: Yes you can. You can do that even without any hard disk at all.

Comment: If you can access the VHDs, you can test both methods without needing to access the machine physically. Realize that any restore method will eventually require physical access to the server

Comment: In continuation to my last comment: unless you intend to restore the OS onto another server at your location, in which case physical access to the original machine is entirely not an issue

Comment: @Dr.Ping Well, seeing as I simply reinstalled the server and restored from the backup, you're incorrect. I'm sorry but I am unable to upvote nor accept your answer as I simply have not (and cannot) use it.

Comment: Well then, I must assume that I did not understand your setup from the start. I cannot understand how you reinstalled an offline server without physical access. At least you got it back up and thus this thread is no longer fruitful

Comment: Unless the server is running on esxi or another type 1 hypervisor. But you didn't mention that, so probably not

Comment: @Dr.Ping We don't have threads on Stack Exchange- this isn't a forum. I've already told you how I did it; moved the backups off the backup drive and reinstalled the server, and then restored from backup.

Answer (score -1):

Good. Easier :) Two ways to do this.

Method (1) Take an empty disk and hook it into a functional computer, as an additional disk. Create 2 partitions on it. One partition ntfs size=490MB. Do NOT make this partition larger than 490MB. Give it a letter, I'll use K in my example. Second partition=whatever you want. Assign it a letter as well. I'll use M in my example. The second partition will be [eventually] be the C: drive on your restored machine.

Copy the contents of the vhd into the second partition.

Open cmd as admin and type:

bcdboot M:\Windows /s K:

Go into Disk Management and make sure that the 490MB partition is Primary and set Active

Remove the disk and try to boot it. It should work.

Once booted, remove the letter from the 490MB partition. It's supposed to be hidden.

Second method. Copy the contents of the vhd into a disk, and boot up with a Windows installation disk or recovery media. There you'll have an option to repair the boot.

I'd try the first method first. Needless to say, don't delete the vhd until you're sure that you're back up with a running system

If you like, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744347(v=ws.10).aspx for more info on BCD

Comment: Any news? Did it work?